# Chef-client startup output fail on stdout but process is running

Tags: ubuntu, chef-infra

I ran into a weird behavior with all my chef-clients. When i perform a :

```
sudo service chef-client start
```

I see `[fail]` on the console. However:

```
ps -ef | grep chef
```

show a `chef-client` process is running.

In the same way if I run:

```
sudo service chef-client stop
```

I also see `[fail]`, but the process still running. There is no way to kill it...

Before it was working like a charm... ( Env => Ubuntu 10.04 as VM's )

FYI: `/var/log/chef/client.log` output no issues and the run list is executed as well (also in debug level from client.rb).

Answer (score 0):

Ohai!

I would not recommend posting issues like these on StackOverflow. Given the debugging steps you've taken, I would recommend opening a bug report on [Chef's ticket tracker](https://tickets.opscode.com) or search for existing issues that match your use case.

I suspect this issue has been fixed since you posted the original issue, but if it has not, the ticket tracker is your best bet.